# How to import JSON File into a TypeScript file?

Tags: json, angular, google-maps, typescript, maps

I am building a map application using Angular Maps and want to import a JSON file as a list of markers defining locations. I'm hoping to use this JSON file as marker[] array inside the app.component.ts . Instead of defining a hardcoded array of markers inside the TypeScript file.

What is the best process of importing this JSON file for use in my project? Any direction greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can see my answer as it is applicable to Angular 7+

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Aonepathan's one-liner was working for me until a recent typescript update.

I found Jecelyn Yeen's [post](https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79) which suggests posting this snippet into your TS Definition file

add file `typings.d.ts` to the project's root folder with below content

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

and then import your data like this:

`import * as data from './example.json';`

### update July 2019:

Typescript 2.9 ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule)) introduced a better, smarter solution. Steps:

1. Add `resolveJsonModule` support with this line in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
```

the import statement can now assumes a default export:

`import data from './example.json';`

and intellisense will now check the json file to see whether you can use Array etc. methods. pretty cool.

Comment: This method worked for me and seems to be the cleanest and most direct way to solving the problem.

Comment: This worked for me as well - super slick! NOTE: You need to restart your dev server for this to compile correctly.

Comment: @RossRawlins restart your project.

Comment: import * as data from './example.json'; and subscribing json which one is preferred and why to subscribe if we can import directly?

Comment: Thank you for the link. The article has been updated to work with typescript 2.9+

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot find module '*.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extensionts(2732)`

Comment: I needed to also add `"esModuleInterop": true,` as specified in the typescript docs, however they also say to use `commonjs` as the `module` instead of `esnext`. This seems to work with either. Is there any reason to switch to commonjs (as mentioned in the docs) as oppose to stick with the default of esnext?

Comment: same as comments above I needed `"esModuleInterop":true`. Also VS code still is showing me an error.. but everything works fine

Comment: I had to add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in the `compilerOptions` as well with a fresh Angular 9.1.11 project.

Comment: restarting VS Code got rid of the error `Consider using '--resolveJsonModule'`for me.

Comment: This change break the `import * as moment from 'moment'` statement. Changing it to `import moment from 'moment'` worked. Also, VS Code restart was required.

Comment: While importing a JSON file works, this should be considered an **anti-pattern**, since data does **not** belong together with the code. If your JSON file is more than a couple of kilobytes then you will be better off using [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) — apart from separating data and code, this will also allow you to have a progress loader and a fluid UI if your data is big.

Comment: it is returning undefined

Answer (score 70):

As stated in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/9phvw1/pro_tip_with_angular_7_you_can_import_json_files/), after Angular 7, you can simplify things to these 2 steps:

1. Add those three lines to `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

2. Import your json data:

```
import myData from '../assets/data/my-data.json';
```

And that's it. You can now use `myData`in your components/services.

Comment: What is `esModuleInterop` for?

Comment: @giovannipds it is for default json imports

Comment: In my case, Angular 10 and Typescript 4.0.2, I did not need `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports"`

Comment: Only solution that wokred for me :)

Answer (score 31):

Thanks for the input guys, I was able to find the fix, I added and defined the json on top of the app.component.ts file:

```
var json = require('./[yourFileNameHere].json');
```

This ultimately produced the markers and is a simple line of code.

Comment: I got `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.` Solved by adding `declare var require: any;`, as explained in comments of accepted answer for question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104114/cannot-find-name-require-after-upgrading-to-angular4/43122829.

Comment: @Ben, you need to add the node type to your tsconfig. i.e. `"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": ["node"]
  },` Here is the related answer for those who require it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35961176/1754995

Comment: Hi @aonepathan, I hope you can help me: I have a library that use require to read a json file. `var json = require('./[yourFileNameHere]');` without the extension. At compile time I have an error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve [yourFileNameHere] in [file name]` do you have any idea to bypass this issue?

Answer (score 26):

Here is complete answer for Angular 6+ based on @ryanrain answer:

From [angular-cli doc](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration), json can be considered as assets and accessed from standard import without use of ajax request.

Let's suppose you add your json files into "your-json-dir" directory:

1. add "your-json-dir" into angular.json file (:

   `"assets": [
     "src/assets",
     "src/your-json-dir"
   ]`
2. create or edit typings.d.ts file (at your project root) and add the following content:

   `declare module "*.json" {
       const value: any;
       export default value;
   }`

   This will allow import of ".json" modules without typescript error.
3. in your controller/service/anything else file, simply import the file by using this relative path:

   `import * as myJson from 'your-json-dir/your-json-file.json';`

Comment: What if I don't have a typings.d.ts file?

Comment: then you have to create one at your project root with only the step 2 content

Comment: Important note: Add the custom typing file to typeRoots in tsconfig.json
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/typings.d.ts"],

Answer (score 18):

**First solution** - simply change the extension of your .json file to .ts and add `export default` at the beginning of the file, like so:

```
export default {
   property: value;
}
```

Then you can just simply import the file without the need to add typings, like so:

```
import data from 'data';
```

---

**Second solution** get the json via HttpClient.

Inject HttpClient into your component, like so:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

and then use this code:

```
this.http.get('/your.json').subscribe(data => {
  this.results = data;
});
```

https://angular.io/guide/http

**This solution has one clear adventage** over other solutions provided here - it doesn't require you to rebuild entire application if your json will change (it's loaded dynamically from a separate file, so you can modify only that file).

Comment: first solution is good if your data is static and will not change for a very long time; it will save you unnecessary http requests, but if this data changes constantly, then use the second solution sent by server or even consider adding it to a database if the data set is huge

Answer (score 16):

I had read some of the responses and they didn't seem to work for me. I am using Typescript 2.9.2, Angular 6 and trying to import JSON in a Jasmine Unit Test. This is what did the trick for me.

Add:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
```

To `tsconfig.json`

Import like:

```
import * as nameOfJson from 'path/to/file.json';
```

Stop `ng test`, start again.

Reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/31/announcing-typescript-2-9/#json-imports

Comment: This was the best solution for me. No typings file needed, _and_ TS can resolve the property names for you.

Comment: This is a great solution, you don't even have to use JSON.parse(). It's a common TS object right out of the box!

Answer (score 13):

As of [Typescript 2.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html), one can simply add:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true
}
```

to the `tsconfig.json`.  Thereafter, it's easy to use a json file (*and* there will be nice type inference in VSCode, too):

`data.json`:

```
{
    "cases": [
        {
            "foo": "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

In your Typescript file:

`import { cases } from './data.json';`

Answer (score 11):

**Angular 10**

You should now edit the **`tsconfig.app.json`** (notice the **"app"** in the name) file instead.

There you'll find the `compilerOptions`, and you simply add `resolveJsonModule: true`.

So, for example, the file in a brand new project should look like this:

```json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For Angular 7+,

1) add a file "typings.d.ts" to the project's root folder (e.g., src/typings.d.ts):

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

2) import and access JSON data either:

```
import * as data from 'path/to/jsonData/example.json';
...
export class ExampleComponent {
    constructor() {
        console.log(data.default);
    }

}
```

or:

```
import data from 'path/to/jsonData/example.json';
...
export class ExampleComponent {
    constructor() {
        console.log(data);
    }

}
```

Comment: data.default was hanging me up. Thanks for the full example!

Comment: Be careful about the path to your json file because it's relevant to the file you import the file e.g. if you have a service in `src/app/services/` folder and your json is in `src/assets/data/` folder you have to specify it like `../../assets/data/your.json`

Comment: It work perfectly, but why typings.d.ts file is needed?

Answer (score 6):

In angular7, I simply used

```
let routesObject = require('./routes.json');
```

My routes.json file looks like this

```
{

    "routeEmployeeList":    "employee-list",
    "routeEmployeeDetail":      "employee/:id"
}
```

You access json items using

```
routesObject.routeEmployeeList
```

Comment: That's it! ;-) All the other options are so hacky!
If you have TSLint will throw a `reuqire` error - just add `declare var require: any;` on top of the class component.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't import a different file.json too.
But I resolved it like this

```
const swaggerDoc = require('../swagger.json')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let fs = require('fs');
let markers;
fs.readFile('./markers.json', handleJSONFile);

var handleJSONFile = function (err, data) {
   if (err) {
      throw err;
   }
   markers= JSON.parse(data);
 }
```