# How to map the interface for json structure in Angular6

Tags: angular

component.ts

```
import * as AssetId from "../../../assetid.json";

export class AssetID {
    abc: number;
    xxx: number;
}

export class Sample {
    public assetId: AssetID = AssetId; // Line no : 9
}
```

assetid.json

```
{
    "abc": 3,
    "xxx": 4
}
```

In line # 9 it creates an error like

TS2322: Type 'typeof "*.json"' is not assignable to type 'AssetID'.
Property 'abc' is missing in type 'typeof "*.json"'

I wanted to map this json format to void `'any'` type in the typescript code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use like this

```
interface IAssetid {
    abc: number;
    xxx: number;
}
```

Secondly you should import const from ts file instead of json

```
export const assetid = {
    'abc': 3,
    'xxx': 4
};
```

For more info, read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46991300/3326275