# How to configure raw-loader in Angular 7 to load text files?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I want to use a raw-loader with my Angular 7 to import text files into my TypeScript source code. I've found plenty of information on the subject and spent a few hours trying to get it to work, but I can not get it to work.

I start by creating a new project

```
ng new example --defaults --minimal
```

I create a text file at `/src/app/example.txt` with the message "Hello World"

I then modify the `app.component.ts` file to import this text file.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import str from 'example.txt';

alert(str);

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: ``,
    styles: []
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

I see a `Cannot load module "example.txt"` error in WebStorm, and when I run `ng build` and I get the following error.

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(2,17): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'example.txt'

So I Googled how to resolve this issue and I found this answer.

[How to import JSON File into a TypeScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991237/how-to-import-json-file-into-a-typescript-file)

I then add a `/src/typings.d.ts` file with the following contents, and this fixes the error in WebStorm.

```
declare module "*.txt" {
    const value: string;
    export default value;
}
```

I run `ng build` again and the error message changes to say it can't find the module.

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'example.txt' in 'C:\work\temp\example\src\app'

After some lengthy Googling, I figure that I need to add a raw-loader to Angular using a custom webpack configuration. Which leads me to this blog post with instructions.

https://codeburst.io/customizing-angular-cli-6-build-an-alternative-to-ng-eject-a48304cd3b21

So I install *custom-webpack*

```
npm i -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack
```

I edit my `angular.json` so that the build uses `extra-webpack.config.js` like so.

```
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js"
            },
```

I create the `extra-webpack.config.js` in the same folder as `angular.json` with the following contents.

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.txt$/,
                use: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I try building again `ng build` but get the same error.

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'example.txt' in 'C:\work\temp\example\src\app'

I have been unable to get past this point, and everything I've Googled so far seems to imply that this is *how* it's supposed to be done. `Module not found` error messages are very broad and I can not find anything specific to Angular 7.

Comment: I see you have put "Hello world", but do you intend to use example.txt it as for  static strings?

Comment: @Vega I need large strings that are also part of the bundle. I know this is possible with webpack as I've done this before on other JavaScript projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Working in Angular 9,10 with Ivy**

So I finally got it working, from [this comment on an issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3879#issuecomment-358920021), here's the steps I took, if anyone else is looking for help.

1. `yarn add -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack raw-loader`
2. Change `angular.json` to use `@angular-builders/custom-webpack`

```json
...
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
    "options": {
      "customWebpackConfig": {
        "path": "./webpack.partial.js"
      },
  ...
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "PROJECTNAME:build"
    },
  ...
```

3. add file `webpack.partial.js` next to `angular.json`

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(txt|md)$/, loader: 'raw-loader' }
    ]
  } 
};
```

4. add type declaration in file `./types/textfile.d.ts`

```js
declare module '!raw-loader!*' {
  const contents: string;
  export = contents;
}
```

5. make sure that your `tsconfig` file knows about `textfile.d.ts`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
...
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "./types"],
...                                       // ^ this is important
}
```

6. import your text files using *require* syntax

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

const myText = require('!raw-loader!./my-text-file.txt');

@Component({
  template: `<pre>{{myText}}</pre>`,
})
export class ChangeLogComponent {
  myText = myText;
}
```

7. Done! The project should serve/build in angular 9,10 now

Comment: I got an error with this config `An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined`

Answer (score 16):

I figured it out, and the answer was on the raw-loader documentation page. At the bottom it explains that you have to prefix the import path with `raw-loader!`

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/#examples

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import str from 'raw-loader!./example.txt';

alert(str);

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: ``,
    styles: []
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

I found this very difficult to figure out. You have to figure out how to get TypeScript to recognise the modules, then you have to configure Angular to use the loader and then you have to know how to correctly import the file.

None of the Google search results showed everything together as it related to Angular 7. So I found this turns up in search results for other people.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work at all, would you be able to link a repository or stackblitz?

Comment: I had to use `!!raw-loader!absolute/path/to/file` per the same instructions. Thanks!