# How to get CSS file content of component in Angular 7?

Tags: css, angular, angular7

I'd like to get the CSS file content of a component.

For example:

hello-world.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-hello-world',
    template: `<h1>Hello World</h1>`,
    styleUrls: ['./hello-world.component.css']
})

export class HelloWorldComponent {
    getCSSContent(){
    }
}
```

hello-world.component.css:

```
h1 {
    color: red;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

I expect getCSSContent function to return:

```
h1 {
    color: red;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: try something like this:  `this.http.get('./app.component.css').subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data', data);
  })` (http request with httpClient)

Comment: You can't get the CSS at run-time. You can't access the original CSS source code or find the `<script>` tag created by Angular. What I did, was to make a copy of the CSS file to my `/assets/` folder and read it from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the folder 'src' add a new file with following name:

```
typings.d.ts
```

with the following content:

```
declare module '*.css';
```

In your component add:

```
import helloWorldCss from './hello-world.component.css'
```

and you can read your css with

```
getCSSContent(){
    return helloWorldCss;
}
```

I recognized some weird text at the end of the helloWorldCss variable.. maybe you have to trim it.

Comment: This will not work. `helloWorldCss` will be the WebPack module that was created at compile time. I know, because I tried this same thing last week. :)

Comment: are you sure? I tested it with ng serve and with publishing it with IIS and it is working..

Comment: I was using a raw-loader at the time. Maybe that changed how imports are handled. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714565/how-to-configure-raw-loader-in-angular-7-to-load-text-files

Comment: you saved my day! this is the second time your answer helped me. thank you!