# Angular (7) component accepts only html files

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Component is defined like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

I would like to load in some specific components instead of "app.component.html" a file with extention htm "app.component.htm"

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.htm',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
```

from some reason it doesnt work it says:

```
ERROR in ./app.component.htm 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
<p>
  app component works!
</p>
｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Please help me find a way to load an htm file? I am aware that there is a way to bootstrap with Webpack, I would like to keep the current build of ng-serve\cli angular.json!

Thank you!

Comment: please provide us with the full ts file

Comment: becuause according to angular there is no file  like htm so not support  it only work if you are using angularjs

Comment: What forces you to use .htm rather than .html files ?

Comment: There is a process to use a [custom builder](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/7.x.x/packages/dev-server#builders) to generate a custom webpack configuration that is merged with the existing configuration, allowing you to specify custom loaders for non-standardized file types.  I've never actually done it myself, however, so I don't know the exact syntax for what you are needing....

Comment: also bear in mind, this appears to be changing in 8.x so it might be a dead end as well....

Comment: what is your angular and angular cli version? I try in angular 8 and it is working! @Mike

Comment: please paste your `webpack.config.js` file here, 
This can be helpful @Mike

Comment: @MHS are you sure? on angular8 i can templateUrl htm files?

Comment: @Mike yes im sure. i test it!

Comment: @MHS Post it as an answer i will accept it and bounty you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your angular version to angular 8, this is fixed in angular 8.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.htm',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be hard to modify how angular load its template files but you can use `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` combined with `raw-loader` import your `htm` file in `component.ts` and instead using `templateUrl` in your component config use `template` and set it with imported value. The solution is almost described in this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714565/how-to-configure-raw-loader-in-angular-7-to-load-text-files) with some changes it works for you too :

> 1. `npm i -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack raw-loader`  install required packages
> 2. Configure angular.json like below :

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser", // change builder
            "options": {
                "customWebpackConfig": { // add custom config
                     "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js"
                  }, // keep the rest same
```

> 3. Add `extra-webpack.config.js` file into same directory with `angular.json` with contents like below :

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.htm$/, // this just tells use raw-loader to load *.htm files
        use: 'raw-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

> 4. Add `typings.d.ts` file into your  `src` folder with content (this will avoid typescript import errors):

```
declare module '*.htm' {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

> 5. And in your component import `htm` file with raw loader

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import str from 'raw-loader!./app.component.htm';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: str, // notice not url just string
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

I have managed to run this configuration in my local but can't manage to make it work in stackblitz. Non working Stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5gcljj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)