# Angular read variable default value from file

Tags: angular, typescript

I know one can read `.json` files from disk at compile time and use them in component like:

```
import * as configFromFile from './my-file.json';
...
let config = configFromFile;
```

Is there a way to load file in similar manner that is not `.json`, for example '.txt' or '.csv' file and initialise `string` variable with it's content?

Comment: No it's not possible because JSON means Javascript Object Notation so can be serialize/deserialize as a simple object literal not the case in front of '.csv' or 'txt'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714565/how-to-configure-raw-loader-in-angular-7-to-load-text-files