# Is there a simple or idiomatic way to access a file in an Angular unit test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, xmlhttprequest, karma-jasmine, webpack-dev-server

I have the default setup for unit tests (Jasmine and Karma). I need to write a unit test for a function that reads a provided `Element` node from an `XMLDocument`. While I could generate the DOMs programatically, I already have example XML files in the asset folder and it would be easiest and most realistic to parse those the same way I do in the actual app. However, providing the files to the unit tests seems to be very difficult. Since the thing I'm trying to accomplish is basic and probably done a lot, I'm hoping there might be a simple solution I'm looking over.

I know I can copy-and-paste the XML source into a string literal, but the files I want to use are 20-50 kB and contain quotes, so I'm trying to avoid that. From what I've read online [such as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714565/how-to-configure-raw-loader-in-angular-7-to-load-text-files), the way to import files is with raw-loader. However, that takes a lot of work to setup and that method is now out of date in favor of [asset modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/). Angular's HttpClientTestingModule doesn't help me because it requires I already have the string in memory, which defeats the purpose of loading an asset with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the solution can be almost as simple as installing an npm package and then following MGX's answer.

### Declaring and Importing

Assuming the default configuration for Angular CLI 17, to declare a module, just add a file with any name ending with a [`.d.ts`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html) in the /src/ directory. You then use `declare module 'expression'`, where 'expression' seems to follow a regex-like syntax. `'*.xml'` is all you need for it to automatically apply to all xml files, while you can also make it more specific. I ended up with this:

```js
declare module '*.xml' {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

As MGX said, you then need to import the file you want to read, not the `.d.ts` file.

### Configuring raw-loading

If you just do that, it still won't work. You will get an error:

> Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

According to the docs, the fix for this involves overriding the default settings for webpack, either with something like [this](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#loaders):

```js
module: {
  rules: [{ test: /\.xml$/, use: 'raw-loader' }],
},
```

or like [this](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#resource-assets):

```js
module: {
  rules: [{ test: /\.xml/, type: 'asset/source' }],
},
```

However, manually fiddling with the the webpack config will mess up Angular CLI's scripts. Many, but not all, of the ways said to edit the config are out of date. Fortunately, [Angular Builders](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack), a tool for making custom build scripts with Angular, is actively maintained.

Instead of trying that first, I tried the package [raw-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-loader). It has been archived for more than three years, but it worked for me in Angular 17.

I just had to install it:

```
npm install raw-loader --save-dev
```

and edit my import statement slightly:

```js
import XML from 'raw-loader!file.xml';
```

and then I got the contents of the file as a string in `XML`.

### Parsing the String

To actually use the XML data, I still had to parse the string, but that is relatively trivial. Since Angular is a web framework, I used the browser's api to parse the string into an [`XMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLDocument), similar to a web pages DOM representation.

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc: XMLDocument = parser.parseFromString(XML, "text/xml");
```

For more information, check out the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/) guide on XML.

For those who don't reliably have that API, or who think parsing to a DOM is overkill, look into [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) or [fast-xml-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In older times to import a JSON file in your TS code you could add a `d.ts` file with this syntax

```js
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

Maybe you could try to do the same with XML ?

Note : use it with the default export, i.e. `import XML from "file.xml";`

Comment: I got further, but that alone wasn't enough. I got this error when running ng test:
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> > [beginning of file text]

This looks like the raw-loader thing. I'll have to read up on the up-to-date webpack documentation and then try it again. Thanks for the help!