# How to inject to service some data?

Tags: angular

I'm using `angular 9` and I need to inject come configuration data to the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private auth: any;

  constructor(private authConfig: AppConfig) {
  }
}
```

and I need to inject `AppConfig` to the service.
How can I do this?

Comment: where do you set `AppConfig`

Comment: @malbarmavi I want to set ```AppConfig``` in the ```app.module.ts``` class.

Comment: You want to inject a configuration object, right? Do you need your deployment tool to replace values in the config depending on what environment you're deploying to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just create a service and decorated with injectable decorator and set the provideIn to root(this will make the service singleton).

*AppConfig*

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn:"root"
})
export class AppConfig {

  url:string;
  port:number;

}
```

then you can inject the service to appNodule ad set the proprty

```js
...
export class AppModule {

  constructor(config:AppConfig) { 
    config.url = '127.0.0.1';
    config.port = 3000;
  }
 }
```

after that you inject the appConfig to any component and service in you app

Answer (score 1):

If `AppConfig` is a `service`, you should easily inject it into `AuthService` in the way you did it. Otherwise, if `AppConfig` is not a service and Angular is not able to inject it (since is not managable by angular), then you propably need to make the fields in `AppConfig` static or make an instace of it in `AuthConfig` manualy, or make it a singleton, or even add it to providers section in `AppModule`. But i think you should let Angular to manage it and if it's not a `service`, add it into `providers`

Answer (score 1):

**1. Use static data**

For simple object based configuration data `{url: "/login", ... } I suggest you use a simple JSON file. You can read about how to import a JSON file to an Angular project in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991237/how-to-import-json-file-into-a-typescript-file)

**2. use a dedicated typescript class**

To utilize the advantages of typescript, you can declare a simple class file, and collect your configuration there as **static** attributes, bound to the class:

```
export class AppConfig{
  public static xy = "..."
}
```

then import it anywere with `myVariable = AppConfig.xy` (don't forget to Import it)

**3. Use environment.ts**

This is already in Angular, you can use the environment-based configurations, read more about `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` [here](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/separating-production-and-development-http-urls-using-environment-ts-file-in-angular-4c2dd0c5a8b0). It's much like the 2nd point, but the file is replaced with a different file if you run `ng build` or `ng build --prod`.

**4. Runtime configuration**

After you understand the advantages-disadvantages of the earlier examples, you might wonder if we can provide configuration only in runtime, maybe based on some dynamic rules?  Yep, this is possible, however a bit more complicated, but you can inject configurations before a module starts, even from an asyncron call, by utilizing   `provide: APP_INITIALIZER`. Read more about it [here](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/01/ng-app-runtime-config/)

Comment: I think the environment.ts is the best case here 

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a static json file.

1. Create a `config.json` file containing your config in `src/assets/` folder of the app.
2. Use HTTP to retrieve the config in the service.

auth.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.http.get('/assets/config.json').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-local-json-file-ju2ahq)

Comment: the  can work but you don't need to do http request everytime you need to read the config value so you can make request and store the data somewhere like constant nr localStorage 

Answer (score 1):

That's what the environment is for.

`src/environment.ts`
and
`src/environment.prod.ts`

The default content is:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false
};
```

or for the prod environment

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

so you provide your config as e.g.

```
import {AppConfig} from '../app/models/app-config';

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  authConfig: {
    clientID: 'oidc-client',
    // stuff or other
  } as AppConfig
};
```

And the same or other for the prod environment.

And you import it like

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  private authConfig = environment.authConfig;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

It will be automatically replaced with the configuration in `environment.prod.ts` for production builds.

Comment: the environment option is one of the best 

Answer (score 0):

this jsut another way you can store the configration in a json file and put the file in the asset folder ,then you can read the file by using 'import' like this

```js
import * as  config from '~/src/assets/app.config.json';
console.log('‍♂️',config)
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pze5bn)