# Angular 8 not under rootDir when i add json file

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have added some json file to my library, but when I build it there is error my.json file not under rootDir.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, kindly go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to access the .json file as part of the application build process (i.e. not via [http](https://angular.io/guide/http)), you will will need to put it into the `assets` folder in your project.

More information about the folder structure of an Angular application [here](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#application-project-files).

You can then follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51040468/2627160) to access the data from your components.