# use server environment variable on image

Tags: angular, kubernetes

I have an app written in angular4,
I am running on production and sandbox,

I create an image and then deploy on kubernetes

I have some environment variables differnt to sandbox and production , currently I build two differnt images one for sandbox and one for 
production:

environments under `src/envirnments`:

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  server_url: 'https://api.example.com/app/',
};
```

**environment.sandbox.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  server_url: 'https://api-sandbox.example.com/app/',
};
```

building image:

**production** : `ng build --prod`

**sandbox**:
`ng build--prod --env=sandbox`

now, how can I use external environment varibales instead? 
somthing like `applicatoion.getEnvirnment('server_url')`, like this I dont need to create an image for each environment?

this is my `deployment.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: angular-web-app
  namespace: production
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  strategy:
      type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: angular-web-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: angular-web-app
        image: us.gcr.io/my-com/angular-web-app:06.01.2018
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: SERVER_URL
          value: https://api.example.com
```

here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

building the image:

```
ng build --prod --env=sandbox
docker build --rm -t ${REGISTRY}/${CONTAINER}:${TAG} .
```

I added  the environment variable to the deployment and I want the app to take the value from there

Answer (score 12, accepted):

alternativly you can read from  local config json , and then use volumes,
 having seperate config map for each of you environments [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275995/angular4-how-do-access-local-json)

under `src/assets/config` put the config json,

in your code read the url from the config file:

```
private getConfigJSONFile() {
     return this.http.get("/assets/config/env-vars.json").map((res:any) => res.json())
   }
```

now create the config on kubernetes:

here is the config file:

**configs/env-variables.json**

```
{
  "api_server_url": "https://api.example.com"
}
```

create the config

```
kubectl create configmap angular-env-vars --from-file=env-vars.json=configs/env-variables.json
```

use volumes in your deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: angular-web-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  strategy:
      type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: angular-web-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: angular-web-app
        image: us.gcr.io/my-com/angular-web-app:06.01.2018
        volumeMounts:
        - name: env-vars
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/config
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
      - name: env-vars
        configMap:
          name: angular-env-vars
```