# Angular 2 and 4 Major differences?

Tags: angular, typescript

Actually im new to angular JS. We started to learn angular 4 but there are no much tutorials on angular 4. If it is fine to learn Angular 2 for Angular 4, Hope there was no much differences between 2 and 4.

Can any one provide link of angular 4 and what are the major changes between them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Angular 4 and from where I can learn more about it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692462/what-is-angular-4-and-from-where-i-can-learn-more-about-it)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-rc1-2017-02-24

Comment: I asked for major differences between 2 and 4.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial.

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing path breaking between angular 2 and angular 4 like angular 1 and angular 2. They are just doing it to maintain SEMVER(Sementic Versioning). Angular 2 is stable now so it would be better to prefer angular 2 instead of angular 4.

Angular 2 was a complete rewrite of AngularJS 1.x with many new concepts. Angular 4 however is the next version of Angular 2. The underlying concepts are still the same and if you have already learned Angular 2 you’re well prepared to switch to Angular 4 now.

The reason it’s Angular 4 and not Angular 3 is that the Angular Router package has already been in version 3 before. The Angular team would like to avoid confusion and decided to skip version 3 for Angular and continue with Version 4.

Comment: Thanks for the information..!!

Comment: Angular 4 is just relased but mostly we are using angular 2 plugins only. There is nothing much worry about angular 4.

Comment: nicely copied from here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224658/what-are-the-differences-between-angular2-and-angular4

Comment: Im wanting to get into Angular. Most tutorials i find are 2. Can i run with that or should i specifically look for 4 tutorials?

Answer (score -3):

#### I found some major differences in Angular2 and Angular4

1. Angular2 displays all the `.JS` files into the `app.component` folder but in Angular4 it is in encrypted mode for the developer. 
2.If we create any new component we need to come and change the `app.module.ts` files every time but with respect to Angular4, it's automatically attached whenever we create a new component.